# ImageResizer throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." after update

Tags: c#, azure, imageresizer

I'm in the process of trying to update our solution with the latest ImageResizer packages from NuGet.

After updating, I got the below null exception. So I tried reverting my solution and updating the packages again. Same problem.
I also tried using the diagnostics page inbuilt in ImageResizer, but this also has the same problem.
There has been no problems during NuGet updates.

StackTrace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.ParseName(String typeName) +8
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.FindPluginType(String searchNameString) +99
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.add_plugin_by_name(String name, NameValueCollection args) +16
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.loadPluginsInternal() +214
   ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.LoadPlugins() +93
   ImageResizer.Configuration.Config..ctor(ResizerSection config) +393
   ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.get_Current() +109
   ImageResizer.InterceptModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +276
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +536
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296
```

Resizer settings in web.config:

```
  <resizer>
    <plugins>  
      <add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/cloud/" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=XXX" endpoint="https://XXX.windows.net/" />
      <add logging="true" />
      <add name="DiskCache" />
    </plugins>
    <clientcache minutes="60" />
    <diskcache enabled="true" dir="~/App_Data/DiskCache" AutoClean="true" hashModifiedDate="true" subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" asyncWrites="false" asyncBufferSize="10485760" />
    <cleanupStrategy startupDelay="00:05" minDelay="00:00:20" maxDelay="00:05" optimalWorkSegmentLength="00:00:04" targetItemsPerFolder="400" maximumItemsPerFolder="1000" avoidRemovalIfCreatedWithin="24:00" avoidRemovalIfUsedWithin="4.00:00" prohibitRemovalIfUsedWithin="00:05" prohibitRemovalIfCreatedWithin="00:10" />
  </resizer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the error message that the error occurs at `PluginConfig.ParseName(String typeName)` - as this is a null reference error, this strongly implies the name is null.

Looking at the plugins section of your config it is then apparent that you have not specified a name for the `logging` plugin:

```
<add logging="true" />
```

The [documentation](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/logging) says that this is the correct syntax:

```
<add name="Logging" />
```